# MySQL Binary Tree Index order

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, binary-tree

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE
((num=8198747 AND class='A') OR
 (num=1646463 AND class='B') OR
 (num=4099442 AND class='C') OR
 (num=1176312 AND class='A') OR
 (num=2146847 AND class='B') OR
 (num=7000296 AND class='F') OR
 --...about 400 more clauses like this
)

SHOW INDEXES FROM mytable;
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name   |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
| mytable |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id            |
| mytable |          1 | nc_idx   |            1 | num           |
| mytable |          1 | nc_idx   |            2 | class         |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My understanding is that for each of the ~400 clauses in the query, it will do a separate BTREE lookup on `num=XXXXXXXX`. Is there any value in changing the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE
((class='A' AND num IN (8198747, 1176312, ...)) OR
 (class='B' AND num IN (1247910, 1248192, ...)) OR
 (class='F' AND num IN (7244626, 9084903, ...)) OR
 --...for each class in the query
)
```

after adding a new index `cn_idx` on `class` and `num`, in that order?
I think it won't be much faster, since `class` is just one char, and thus the number of BTREE lookups will be the same. But, each subtree will be shorter. Thoughts?

Comment: Assuming your classes go from A-Z, which is 26 characters - it seems pointless to have it indexed as the selectivity is low. On the other hand, and I realize this isn't related to your direct question about B-TREEs - why would anyone have 400 clauses like this in the first place? It seems absolutely ineffective to construct such a query.

Comment: I agree. I didn't write said query, but I'm tasked with optimizing it. How would you write it?

Comment: Since I have no idea what the query is actually supposed to do - I just know I wouldn't index a column that would produce low index selectivity :)

Comment: Basically, I need to query something like 400 rows from a table with over 1 million values. The selectivity of `num` is nearly 1, and that of `class` is nearly 0. I'm starting to think that there is no way around the query I have (which is not _that_ slow).

Comment: If we're talking about InnoDB, you can increase innodb_buffer_pool_size variable in order to squeeze out more performance. However, since you got num with high selectivity - get rid of the index on class as it won't do anything performance-wise, it'll just waste more space for no reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short**

- just stick to `OR`
- the index on num is the only index that will help this query
- an composite index on (num,class) has negligible effect, since num is already very selective

---

Two other ways to write it, using UNION ALL

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (num=8198747 AND class='A')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (num=1646463 AND class='B')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (num=4099442 AND class='C')
UNION ALL
... etc ...
```

This may work well if you don't have too many num/class pairs, as each one will individually perform an index seek.  (A composite index on num/class will work better than num and class indexes single-field indexes.  class/num is less selective)

The second way uses JOIN mechanics, by making a virtual table out of the num/class pairs:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
JOIN (
    select 8198747 as num, 'A' as class union all
    select 1646463, 'B' union all
    select 4099442, 'C' union all
    ... etc ...
    ) v on v.num=t.num and v.class=t.class
```

### Performance comparison

Create a table

```
create table mytable (
id int auto_increment primary key,
num int, 
class char(1), 
other varchar(10), 
date timestamp default current_timestamp) ENGINE InnoDB;
```

Fill it up with 1 million records
(Note: data properties - selectivity: num ~ 1, class ~ 1/26)

```
insert into mytable(num, class, other)
select rand()*100000000, char(rand()*26+65), concat('',rand()*10000000)
from
(select 1 a union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 0) a,
(select 1 a union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 0) b,
(select 1 a union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 0) c,
(select 1 a union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 0) d,
(select 1 a union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 0) e,
(select 1 a union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 0) f
```

Create the indexes

```
create index nc_num on mytable(num);
create index nc_class on mytable(class);
```

#### Select using OR

```
select * from mytable
WHERE
(num=38142659 and class='T') OR
(num=42476845 and class='E') OR
(num=45205882 and class='B') OR
(num=84861596 and class='K') OR
..... 100 in total
```

Output of [Show profiles](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html): (run `set profiling=1;` once. then run the queries. run `show profiles` to see the last timings)

```
Duration: 0.00003025
```

Explain extended (add `explain extended` before the query)

```
"id";"select_type";"table";"type";"possible_keys";"key";"key_len";"ref";"rows";"Extra"
"1";"SIMPLE";"mytable";"range";"nc_num,nc_class";"nc_num";"5";NULL;"125";"Using where"
```

#### Select using UNION ALL between num/class

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (num=38142659 AND class='T') UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (num=42476845 AND class='E') UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (num=45205882 AND class='B') UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (num=84861596 AND class='K') UNION ALL
.... 100 in total
```

Show Profile

```
Duration: 0.00069525
```

Explain extended

```
"id";"select_type";"table";"type";"possible_keys";"key";"key_len";"ref";"rows";"Extra"
"1";"PRIMARY";"mytable";"ref";"nc_num,nc_class";"nc_num";"5";"const";"1";"Using where"
"2";"UNION";"mytable";"ref";"nc_num,nc_class";"nc_num";"5";"const";"1";"Using where"
"3";"UNION";"mytable";"ref";"nc_num,nc_class";"nc_num";"5";"const";"1";"Using where"
"4";"UNION";"mytable";"ref";"nc_num,nc_class";"nc_num";"5";"const";"1";"Using where"
... etc
```

#### Select using Union All to build up a virtual table

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
JOIN (
select 41805446 num, 'X' collate utf8_general_ci class union all
select 84867135, 'P' union all
select 52747446, 'R' union all
.... etc...
) v on v.num=t.num and v.class=t.class
```

Show profile

```
Duration: 0.00026100
```

Explain extended

```
"id";"select_type";"table";"type";"possible_keys";"key";"key_len";"ref";"rows";"Extra"
"1";"PRIMARY";"<derived2>";"ALL";NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;"100";""
"1";"PRIMARY";"t";"ref";"nc_num";"nc_num";"5";"v.num";"1";"Using where"
"2";"DERIVED";NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;"No tables used"
"3";"UNION";NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;"No tables used"
"4";"UNION";NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;"No tables used"
....
"101";"UNION";NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;"No tables used"
NULL;"UNION RESULT";"<union2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,...>";"ALL";NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;""
```

#### Select using IN

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE
(class='A' and num in (28538065
)) or (class='B' and num in (70851926
,90457823
,94804149
)) or (class='C' and num in (74179050
,43280101
,24562525
,56859448
,38226813
,33532373
,93501613
,28634136
,8204338
,15636810
)) or (class='D' and num in (26672499
.... etc
```

Show profile

```
Duration: 0.00003125
```

Explain extended

```
"id";"select_type";"table";"type";"possible_keys";"key";"key_len";"ref";"rows";"Extra"
"1";"SIMPLE";"mytable";"range";"nc_num,nc_class";"nc_num";"5";NULL;"136";"Using where"
```

Comment: You do know this is MySQL we're talking about here, not MSSQL? SELECT * doesn't have ANY performance implications here. Unions will only make the whole thing slower, making temp tables and what not. Explanation on what the query does would help definitely, as there's always a better way to achieve something and query with 400 where conditions seems like a mistake in design.

Comment: Great, then you do know how many times the table will be opened in order to do all the UNIONs and how SELECT * works with MySQL and InnodB, which will help you realize why you're wrong. Happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for this extremely detailed comparison. I can see why you have 20k+ points.